Session duration longer than 30 min GA4 Bigquery
Someone could help me? I don't know how it is possible to have sessions with this duration in GA4 BigQuery. (The limit set in GA4 is 30 min, as is by default). What could be happening? I attach an example of a user and their behavior. The number of users with this behavior is small, but it affects my calculations.
enter image description here
Possible solutions or explanation

The session duration timeout in GA4 is the period after your last event or action within a session. There is no limit to the session duration time, so if a user explores your website for several days without taking a break and doesn't close the browser, you may see very long session times. Additionally, if you use the measurement protocol, you can send events even up to 3 days after the session ends.
